# How to hide power bi top left logo and bottom navigation logo, when report is embedded on website?

Tags: web, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have uploaded a power bi report to a website with power bi (Pro subscription), however the report embedded there show "power bi logo" on top and bottom. is there any way possible to replace these logo with company´s logo? Thanks

i tried to find solution on internet but no help!

Comment: Are you use the Publish to Web option? If you are, you can’t change them

Comment: Need to Upload a brand package for that. Refer to the following documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal?view=sql-server-ver16#applying-the-brand-package-to-the-web-portal